# Why do I have to type so many single quotes to escape quotes in dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Could someone explain why I had to type 10 single quotes here just to get it to store '' in the column?  I'm trying to understand the logic to this..

```
exec('UPDATE [SomeTable] SET [SomeColumn] = '''''''''''', [AnotherColumn] = Null ')
```

I kept adding quotes until I got the desired output I wanted but now I would like to know why I had to put in so many quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code to insert '' into the table would look like this:

```
UPDATE [SomeTable] SET [SomeColumn] = '''''', [AnotherColumn] = Null
```

However, because you're executing this inside another string, you'll need to escape the escaped quotes, resulting in the code you gave.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use the equivalent (`CHAR(39)`) if you actually want to store `''` in the database without having to escape it (though I'm not sure if your intent was to store an empty string or to actually store two single quotes):

```
EXEC('
  DECLARE @x TABLE(x VARCHAR(10));
  INSERT @x SELECT CHAR(39) + CHAR(39);
  SELECT x FROM @x;
');
```

I typically do something like this to avoid concatenation and ugly nesting of single quotes when constructing dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SET @sql = 'SELECT foo = $sq$bar$sq$;';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '$sq$', CHAR(39));

SELECT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

No, that doesn't make this specific case any more readable of course, but when you're referencing the same database, table or column multiple times in a big string, it works much better to replace tokens (`$db$`, `$table$`, etc.) than to deal with all the other concatenation mess. IMHO.

Comment: Nice use of REPLACE function indeed and definitely something to consider on my next adventure with dynamic sql.  The only reason I didn't mark this as the answer is because although clever, it does not answer the question at hand.

Comment: Sure, but if you interpret your question as "how do I do this without all these single quotes?" which it probably could have been...

Answer (score 1):

You need/have twelve quotes. Each quote in the string is escaped by a second quote. You would ordinarily need to do `set column = ''''''`, but as this itself is inside a string, each escaped quote should be doubled up, resulting in the twelve quotes you have.